# Azure Devops Pipeline: There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I have created a new pipeline as part of investigating this issue as follows:
New Pipeline > Azure Repos Git > Start pipeline

I have not edited the base template pipeline code, so it looks like this:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

However randomly (at least 1 in every 15), I will see the following warning when running the pipeline:
There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError

Considering that im using their starter pipeline without any changes, I don't think this is an issue with the yaml, but an issue on Azure DevOps / Hosted Agents side.

I also enabled the diagnostic logs, and found the following in Agent_20220611-100355-utc.log:

```
[2022-06-11 10:03:56Z ERR  JobNotification] Connection to monitor port 49100 failed!
[2022-06-11 10:03:56Z ERR  JobNotification] System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (111): Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:49100
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.JobNotification.ConnectMonitor(String monitorSocketAddress)
[2022-06-11 10:03:56Z ERR  JobNotification] Invalid socket address hello. Job Notification will be disabled.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: No suggestions, but I've started getting this using windows-latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from `windows-latest` to `windows-2022` and that cured things for me.  Which is weird because [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) says they are the same thing.

Maybe a similar trick will work for you?  Try `ubuntu-20.04`.

Comment: Yep that was the solution thanks